# Android Quiz App with SQLite database random choice

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am writing a simple multiple choice quiz app. The SQLite database table looks like this:

```
1 Question1 RightAnswer1
2 Question2 RightAnswer2
3 Question3 RightAnswer3 
and so on.
```

The activity layout looks like this.

```
Question TextView
Wrong Answer ListViewItem
Right Answer ListViewItem
Wrong Answer ListViewItem
Wrong Answer ListViewItem
```

I am going to choose Java random to select a random question from the table. My question is - how should I choose wrong answers from the same table so that they don’t coincide with the right answer.
And another question is how can I place the right answer at one of the four TextViews randomly?
Should I use Java Collections.shuffle to shuffle those four positions?

Comment: A question of the same kind has been already answered on SO. I'm not able to find it to provide you with a reference.

Answer (score 0):

I don´t write english very well, but take a look at my solution.

Create one listview of a call question class. In that class contains:
1 - One field string for the question.
2 - One field string for the answer.
3 - One field boolean for wrong or right.

I hope that helps.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can build a class for your sqlite data.

```
public class name{
     private String question;
     private String answer;
     public name(String q,String a){
             question=q;
             question=a;
       }
     public String getQuestion{return question;}
     public String getAnswer {return answer;}
}
```

And after defining this class you can put your datas inside the ArrayList after retrieving from the Sqlite db.

```
ArrayList<your class name> list=new ArrayList<your class name>();
Cursor c=db.query(tablename,new String[]{your columns},null,null,null,null,null);
if(c.moveToFirst(){
    do{
       String question=c.getString(columnName);
       String answer=c.getString(ColumnBame);
       className cls=new className(question,answer);
       list.add(cls);
       }while(c.MoveToNext());
```

Comment: I used Java Random to generate random number and used that number to get a question from the database with cursor but same question repeats very often. How would I choose a question from the array and make sure it is unique? And how would I choose wrong answers from the same array and make sure that they don't include the right answer?

Comment: Ok I got it. I can shuffle the array.